# Are there any R package repository management tools?

Tags: r, repository, package, cran

I'm creating a custom R package repository and would like to replicate the CRAN archive structure whereby old versions of packages are stored in the `src/contrib/Archive/packageName/`directory. I'd like to use the `install_version` function in `devtools` (source [here](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/blob/master/R/install-version.r)), but that function is dependent on having a CRAN-like archive structure instead of having all package versions in `src/contrib/`.

Are there any R package repository management tools that facilitate the creation of this directory structure and other related tasks (e.g. updating the Archive.rds file)?

It would also be nice if the management tools handled the package `type` logic on the repository side so that I can use the same `install.packages()` or `install_version()` code on a Linux server as on my local Mac (i.e. I don't have to use `type="both"` or `type="source"` when installing locally on a Mac).

Comment: You could ask this question at the R-devel mailing list (if you haven't already done so), they know it best. Or maybe even directly from the CRAN maintainers, i.e. Kurt.

Comment: Thanks, I did. I'll post an answer soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:** 
Not really for off-the-shelf use.

**Long answer:**
There are a couple of tools that one can use to manage their repo, but there isn't a coherent off-the-shelf ecosystem yet.

The CRAN maintainers keep a bevy of scripts [here](http://developer.r-project.org/CRAN/QA/) to manage the CRAN repository, but it's unclear how they all work together or which parts are needed to update the package index, run package checks, or manage the directory structure.

The `tools::write_PACKAGES` function can be used to update the package index, but this needs to be updated each time a package is added, updated, or removed from the repository.

M.eik Michalke has created the `roxyPackage` [package](http://reaktanz.de/?c=hacking&s=roxyPackage), which has the ability to automatically update a given repository, install it, etc. The developer has also recently added the ability to have the archive structure mimic that of CRAN with the `archive_structure` function. The downside is the package isn't on CRAN and would probably be better if integrated with `devtools`. It's also brand new and isn't ready for wide use yet.

Finally, I created a small Ruby [script](https://github.com/eshilts/r-repo-updater) that watches a given repository and updates the package index if any files change. However, this is made to work for my specific organization and will need to be refactored for external use. I can make it more general if anyone is interested in it.